# Are the two datetimes equal?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have two methods and I want to combine these two methods. These methods:

```
  public int MonthViewByCardId(int userId, int cardId,int day)
    {
        var date = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(day);
        return Conn.UserAnalyses.Where(d => d.AppUserId == userId && d.CardId == cardId && d.VisitDate > date).Count();
    }
  public int DayViewByCardId(int userId, int cardId,int day)
    {
        var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(day);
        return Conn.UserAnalyses.Where(d => d.AppUserId == userId && d.CardId == cardId && d.VisitDate > date).Count();
    }
```

If I take these two methods into only one method and add 1 and 30 in the day addition section, will it give the same result? I wanted to say

```
var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
var month = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
```

Day and month does this code give the same output if i use it in methods

Comment: this looks wrong `var date = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(day);`  (the AddMonths(day) part)

Comment: Have you write a test case/script to test whether `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1) == DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)` and see the output?

Comment: i haven't tried it, but i would assume that `AddMonths(1)` is **not** the same as `AddDays(30)` since not all months have 30 days.

Comment: Side note: `DateTime.Now` is a current date and time up to the *fractions of second*, so since time passes the two consequent calls will operate with different times.

Comment: @YongShun yes i got different output so i shared it just to be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we're talking about the Gregorian calendar then it's not that straight forward. Only 4 months have 30 days in them - April, June, September and November. February has either 28 or 29 depending on the year and the other 7 have 31 days.

I think the best way to combine these methods would be to have 2 separate parameters:

```
public int ViewByCardId(int userId, int cardId, int months = 0, int days = 0)
{
    var date = DateTime.Now
        .AddMonths(months)
        .AddDays(days);

    return Conn.UserAnalyses
        .Count(d => d.AppUserId == userId && d.CardId == cardId && d.VisitDate > date);
    }
```

This will allow you to use any combination of months/days by optionally specifying them, e.g.

```
ViewByCardId(userId, cardId, days: 20)
```

Note, I also removed the `Where` clause in favour of adding a predicate to `Count`.